# Google Compute Engine Container Port Closed

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, network-programming, google-compute-engine, netcat

I added a firewall rule to open port 8080. If I click the SSH button in the GCE console, and run on the host shell:

```
nc -l -p 8080 127.0.0.1
```

I can detect the opened port. If I then go to the container's shell with:

```
docker run --rm -i -t <image> /bin/sh
```

and run the same netcat command, I can't detect the open port.

I went down this troubleshooting route because I couldn't connect to a `node:alpine` container running the `ws` npm for a demo websocket server. Here is my dockerfile:

```
# specify the node base image with your desired version node:<version>
FROM node:alpine
# replace this with your application's default port
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk --update add git
```

Comment: `docker run --rm -i -t -p 8080:8080 <image> /bin/sh` . Expose the port in the container to the host.

Comment: Yes, fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker run --rm -i -t -p 8080:8080 <image> /bin/sh
```

per [Google Compute Engine Container Port Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736890/google-compute-engine-container-port-closed#comment105623210_59736890)